# formatting ngb-timepicker so it returns as string not an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get ngb-timepicker to return a string instead of an object. At the moment it returns the following:

```
{
  "hour": 13,
  "minute": 30
}
```

but I would like it to return like this:

```
"13:30"
```

This is my html:

```
    <div class="calender"> <ngb-datepicker #dp 
[(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>


<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

With datepicker I could reformat it from an object to a string with this:

```
 constructor(private dateFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {
const string_date = this.dateFormatter.format(this.model);
}
```

Is there a version of NgbDateParserFormatter that works with time?

Comment: if you want to convert object to string you can directly do this JSON.stringify(obj);

Comment: @yer could you explain a bit more..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[(ngModel)]` syntax can only set a data-bound property. If you need to do something more or something different, you can write the expanded form.
The property binding `[ngModel]` takes care of updating the underlying input DOM element. The event binding `(ngModelChange)` notifies the outside world when there was a change in the DOM.

**HTML**

```
 <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time" (ngModelChange)="onTimeChange($event)"></ngb-timepicker>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{newTime}}</pre>
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  public newTime:string='13:30';
  time = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
onTimeChange(value:{hour:string,minute:string})
{
   console.log(value)
   this.newTime=`${value.hour}:${value.minute}`;
}

}
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbootstrap-time)**

Comment: Replace `value.hour + ":" + value.minute;` with `\`${value.hour}:${value.minute};`\`

Comment: @aloisdg I am not aware of this syntax mind shedding some light?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @aloisdg Thanx for the link, I have made the changes:)